# Export JSON data to Excel sheet using ASP.Net MVC Web Api

Tags: javascript, json, excel, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have a Single Page App (SPA) built using Durandal, ASP.net MVC Web API, Breeze and knockout js.

I need to export a list to an Excel sheet that should be downloaded to the download folder on click of a button on the html page.

While I have successfully done that by converting the JSON data to csv format in javascript(on client side), it is taking too much time if the amount of data is large(3000 + rows or it can be around 12000).

I am having problem in sending the excel file as response type from the Web API call made through Breeze.js.

Is there a way to do this in a way which should be a bit fast as it might also be required on mobile devices?

**EDIT**

Below is the code I have written -

JavaScript code for binding -

```
function exportListToExcel() {                          
    DataContext.exportListToExcel().then(function (data) {
        //Do some stuff.                           
    });
}
```

In the Data context file implemented in breeze, the code is returning the promise -

```
function exportListToExcel() {

    function querySucceeded() {
        //return data;
    }
    return util.sendRequest(config.baseApiPath + 'breeze/MyController/ExportListToExcel')
          .then(querySucceeded)
          .fail(queryFailed);
}
```

Below code is the request sent to the Web API. I don't know if it should be HttpPost or something else.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ExportListToExcel()
{
    return ExportListToExcel();
}
```

And below is the back end code -

```
public static HttpResponseMessage ExportListToExcel()
{
    //Method which returns table data. This is working fine though.
    object listObject = GetListData();
    Table listData = (Table)listObject;            
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Report.xlsx";
    HttpResponseMessage File = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<table border=`" + "1px" + "`b>");
        str.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in listData.Columns)
        {                
            str.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=3>" + dc.ColumnName + "</font></b></td>");                
        }

        str.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (DataRow dr in listData.Rows)
        {
            str.Append("<tr>");                              

            for (int i = 0; i < listData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + dr[i].ToString() + "</font></td>");
            }

            str.Append("</tr>");
        }
        str.Append("</table>");


        byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());

        //To write the table to the File content.
        File.Content = new StringContent(temp.ToString());

        return File;                                             
    }
```

This however is not working and in the data context file, queryFailed() method is executed.

I don't know where I am going wrong or what I am missing out here. Also, it  would be much help to let me know how to handle the file/data which the promise returns.

Comment: So, we have a lot going on in this post, and some clarification is necessary.  It would seem you're identifying two problems: a) too much time in conversion, and b) a problem sending an Excel file as a response type.  When you ask, "...a way to do this...a bit fast", are you referring to the conversion, or to time on the wire?  I ask because you mention "mobile".  Also, please provide your response header and content type configurations.  It would help, too, if you could clarify what you mean by "I am having a problem sending..."

Comment: @EricTaylor I have updated the post. Hope it makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Ward's answer.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have an answer on how to have the user download a file in an SPA like this.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Just curious, this may not be applicable, since you're using asp.net could you have used a generic ashx handler and called it like 'window.location = "/helpers(or some other folder)/downloadExcelFile.ashx";' from your datacontext?  Just do all the ExportToExcel code in the handler's ProcessRequest method.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is that BreezeJS is the wrong tool for this particular job ... and I say that as a co-author of BreezeJS.

The trouble begins with the paradigm. I'm having trouble thinking of spreadsheet rows as "entities" in the usual sense of business objects. They seem more like simple data to me.

In this example, we're very far from entity-thinking. You appear to be preparing a big chunk of HTML for display on the client. There is nothing "entity-like" about this.

I have no quarrel with your intent. But I think you should treat this as you would any other raw resource (e.g., images) and fetch it with simple AJAX using whatever component is available to you.

You may be building a hybrid app in which you have both raw data (or HTML) and an entity model. Breeze is a fine tool for the app as long as you apply it appropriately. Your Breeze app is already delegating to a low level AJAX component (e.g., `jQuery.ajax` or Angular's `$http`) and you should be able to find that component in your code base and use it directly for this particular csv task.